# passing arguments to contract file in solidity, when i try to test the contract it returns 0

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, metamask, ganache

I passed the totalSupply in 2_deploy_contract.js

```
const HelioToken = artifacts.require("HelioToken");
module.exports = function (deployer) {
  const intialSupply = 1000000;
  deployer.deploy(HelioToken,intialSupply);
};
```

this is my contract HelioToke.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract HelioToken {
        // constructor
        // set the total number of token 
        // read the total number of token

        uint256 public totalSupply;
        mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

        constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) {
                balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
                totalSupply = _initialSupply;
        }
        
}
```

i tried this code in truffle console

```
truffle(development)> HelioToken.deployed().then(function(i){token=i;})
undefined
truffle(development)> token.totalSupply().then(function(s){supply=s;})
undefined
truffle(development)> supply
BN { negative: 0, words: [ 0, <1 empty item> ], length: 1, red: null }
truffle(development)> supply.toNumber()
0
truffle(development)>
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to give somehow the address and abi of the contract in the console.. otherwise how truffle will know which contract you want? any why are you using the console? better to write tests to try all the functions.. much easier to change and modify

Comment: @MajdTL thanks for your reply, yes I tried in test file its working fine.